# How to achieve scrollable TextView with custom popup on ClickableSpan at span location?

Tags: android, popup, scrollview, spannable

[image]

As shown in above image(subview of some screen), I want to achieve the scrollable text content(from dynamic json data) in which I have color & linked span.

Once user clicked on this span I want to show popup as shown in reference image(consider different angles & scrolls).

Anyone help me for the popup view at span text or any other option:

- Bind dynamic text and generate spannable & clickable text on text view with scrollable content? - **Done**
- How to get exact location of span for text view inside scrollview(scrollable content)?
- How to show popup at that location from span we get?

For Popup in static views I can find few libraries which can help but for content inside scroll it is not working as expected.

- https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView
- https://github.com/runway20/PopoverView

Comment: see `android.text.Spanned`,  `android.text.Layout` and `android.widget.PopupWindow`

Comment: yes ofc this is base classes and I had already looked at those.

Comment: so i hope you know what to do next...

Comment: we can't achieve it as expected specifically for scrollable content as mentioned in question.

Comment: so what is scrollable: text view or content of the green popup?

Comment: TextView is scrollable.

Comment: so you dont have a problem with a scrollable `TextView`: every `TextView` is scrollable by default